# Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier *, or it may have already been ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, uibackgroundtask

My app monitors user location updates (not necessarily significant location change) with:

```
someLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[someLocationManager setDelegate:self];
[someLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

When app (in simulator) is in foreground everything works ok, but when suspending it to background (not terminating), I get this error to the log:

> Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier *, or it may have already been ended

All other answers for this error have no connection to location services, but only generic background task issues.

Comment: It's fine to post your own question/answer but at least make your "question" an actual question. And no need to mention that you are going to answer your own question.

Comment: I think that acting like it's a real question has no benefit.
Presenting a real problem - that's the point, and so I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that the following 3 settings should be made in order for background location update to work properly.
Do this and fix the problem:

1. Make `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key is set (with value as a reason for the permission) in `info.plist`.
2. Make sure to call `[someLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` when asking for permission.
3. Enable `Location Updates` in `Background Modes` in `Capabilities` section in your target settings. Not sure about this one, but sounds right.

Enjoy!

Comment: @AshishKakkad That's perfectly fine.

Comment: You don't mention whether the three posted steps actually fix the error or not. Do they?

Comment: "...should be made in order for background location update to work properly", so yes, it fixes the problem. I edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code at the time of getting location authorization from the user. Because apple changed the default allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates NO from iOS9.

```
'if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}'
```